# On the uniqueness of the solution given by the fixed point theorem - What is the full condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I'm reading some proofs of the existence and uniqueness theorem for ODEs and they all seem to me to be somewhat imprecise about the detail that is bothering me.

I'll state the theorem as it is in my books:

> Let $f:A\subset \mathbb R ^2 \to \mathbb R $ be a continuous function such that $$|f(t,y_2)-f(t,y_1)|\leq L|y_2-y_1|\qquad \forall t\in [-a,a],\quad y_1,y_2\in [-b,b],$$
>   where $[-a,a]\times [-b,b]\subset A$.
>   Then there exists  $0<\delta <a$ such that the solution of the problem $$y'=f(t,y),\qquad y(0)=0 \qquad (\text{CP})$$
>   exists and is unique in $[-\delta , \delta]$.

A solution is a $C^1([-\delta , \delta])$ function that satisfies $(\text {CP})$  and such that $(t,f(t))\in A$ for $t\in [-\delta ,\delta]$.

The proof goes roughly as follows. Let $\varepsilon < b$ and $$Q(\varepsilon)=\{y\in C^1([-\delta ,\delta]):\  ||y||\leq \varepsilon \},$$
where $||\cdot||$ is the $\max$-norm on $C^1([-\delta , \delta])$ .

If for $t\in [-\delta , \delta]$ we let: $$T[y](t)=\intop _0 ^t f(y(t),t)\text d t,$$
it's provable that for $\delta $ sufficiently small, $T$ is a contraction of the complete metric space $Q(\varepsilon)$. It follows that $T$ admits a unique fixed point $y\in Q(\varepsilon )$ which is *the* solution of $(\text {CP})$. [I could be more precise about the proof, let me know if it's needed]

I have some problems understanding how does this prove that the solution is unique (if it does, in the sense that I think). As I see, the proof shows that a solution exists *and is unique in the subset $Q(\varepsilon)$ of $C^1([-\delta ,\delta])$.*

Now, if $y\in C^1([-\delta ,\delta])$ solves $(\text{CP})$, clearly we can find $\delta _y>0$ such that $||y||<\varepsilon$ in $[-\delta _y ,\delta _y]$. But can we prove that *every* $C^1([-\delta , \delta])$ solution is in $Q(\varepsilon)$ for *one* $\delta >0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every solution of $(\text{CP})$ satisfies $y(0) = 0$. Choose $\delta_0 > 0$ and $b_0 > 0$ so that $[-\delta_0,\delta_0] \times [-b_0,b_0] \subset A$. Let

$$M := \sup \{ \lvert f(t,y)\rvert : \lvert t\rvert \leqslant \delta_0,\, \lvert y\rvert \leqslant b_0\}.$$

For $\delta_1 = \min \{\delta_0,\, b_0/M\}$, every solution of $(\text{CP})$ satisfies $\lvert y(t)\rvert \leqslant M\cdot \lvert t\rvert$ on $[-\delta_1,\delta_1]$ by the mean value theorem. Hence every solution on the interval $[-\delta_1,\delta_1]$ belongs to $Q(b_0)$.

A solution needs time to grow above $b$ in absolute value, and if you don't give it enough time, i.e. choose $\delta$ small enough, it must lie in $Q(b)$.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this was my first idea. But how can you say that $|y(t)|\leq M |t|$? Applying the mean value theorem we get: $$|y(t)|=|y'(ht)||t|=|f(y(ht),t)||t|,$$ for some $0<h<1$, that we can estimate with $M$ only if we assume that $|y(ht)|<b_0$, that is more or less what we are trying to prove!

Comment: Let $\delta = \sup \{ \eta > 0 : \lvert y(t)\rvert \leqslant b\text{ for } \lvert t\rvert \leqslant \eta\}$. By continuity, and $y(0) = 0$, we have $\delta > 0$, and $\lvert y(t)\rvert \leqslant M\cdot \lvert t\rvert$ for $\lvert t\rvert \leqslant \delta$. Assuming that $\delta < \delta_1$ leads to a contradiction, since then $\lvert y(\pm\delta)\rvert \leqslant M\delta < b$, so there is a neighbourhood of $\delta$, and one of $-\delta$ on which still $\lvert y(t)\rvert < b$.

Answer (score 0):

If $||y||<b$ then $||y||<c$ for all $c>b$ but... this is not the same that $||y||>b$.

Comment: Hi Martìn, sorry but I don't understand what you mean.